# How to know which Python interpreter to use in VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am using a MacBook, so I already have a Python version preinstalled, but nonetheless I have still installed the latest Python version from the official website.

When I open VSCode and want to select an interpreter, there are now multiple options, with the same version. How do I know which one I should select/select and use as my Python Path? The latest Python version has two interpreters, `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8`, and `/usr/local/bin/python3`. Is there some way to find out which one is better/which one to use?

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of them. But it's recommended

```
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

now. when trying to run this on a console. Edit your .bash_profile and add an alias because mac uses python2.7 and you might have issues with that.

```
alias python=/usr/local/bin/python3
```

Comment: When I do which python3, it shows me the other path though (I thought you should use whatever it says there), does that matter? What does the command really do anyways?

Comment: if you now do python on a terminal you will get default python2.7 this is to prevent you getting python2.7; instead you get what you always want which is python3.

Comment: Why does writing "which python3" in the terminal (before doing what you said) result in it showing me ```/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8``` instead of ```/usr/local/bin/python3``` if that is the recommended path?

Comment: please use /usr/local/bin/python3

Comment: The `/usr/local/bin/python3` is probably a symlink to the framework install.

Comment: Eddwin - Can you explain why this is the recommended path/interpreter?